# Unable to update Cards settings within Sprint Board in ADO

Tags: azure, azure-devops

So I've got both Project Admin and Project Collection Admin rights within ADO, but I'm unable to change any of the Cards settings for my project's sprint board. In the imgur link, you can see the error I'm still getting, and the permissions that have been setup for both groups: https://i.stack.imgur.com/woZJU.jpg

There's not been anything so far that seems like a dead obvious reason for why I wouldn't be able to amend these things, so basically wondering if anyone has seen this before, or if any helpful MS folk happen to know exactly what the fix would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be due to devops access level permissions.
Check your access level under the devops Organization Settings -> Users

Make sure you have "Basic" access instead of "Stakeholder".

See access levels : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/access-levels?view=azure-devops

[image]

Comment: This was exactly the answer, thanks a lot Rimaz!